# NetworkManager Hotspot DHCP pihole

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, dhcp

Fresh installation of 21.04 Desktop on RaspberryPi.
All works Out of the box. I can create a Hotspot.
I install Pi-Hole which will provide DNS & DHCP services (unbound next when this problem solved).
Cannot now create Hotspot that works. The Hotspot configuration file is created but no IP address is assigned to the wifi hardware, so the Hotspot doesn't function.

**Investigation:**

NetworkManager invoked to create the Hotspot.
NetworkManager invokes dnsmasq (or what I assume is the cut down version mentioned in the NetworkManager man).
This fails because pi-hole is listening port 53.
I need NM to use pihole-FTL (that is the dns/dhcp server on pi-hole) but it appears from the manual that the valid entries for this configuration are "dhclient, dhcpcd, and internal"
I can set a manual address to the wifi hardware and it seems to function but it gives that same address as the DNS to the connecting client and so the client has access to the local network but not internet.
In this state the pihole dhcp also assigns an address to the local wifi hardware, but I have gone no further to investigate whether this is functional.

Ideally I need NetworkManager to use the pihole DHCP server rather than its internal dhcp server.

Any other way to make NM use a different dhcp server?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I fixed by uninstalling the dnsmasq package: [nmcli hotspot dhcp not working (solved)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419938/nmcli-hotspot-dhcp-not-working-solved)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1239443)