# nmcli hotspot dhcp not working

Tags: network-manager, dnsmasq

I have ubuntu server arm64 22.04 running on a raspberry pi for use as a wifi hotspot with the internet connection provided by a cellular modem. I'm using networkmanager and modemmanager to manage the connections. All packages are updated.

I have been able to create a wifi hotspot using nmcli and I can connect other devices to it but the connected devices stay on "self assigned ip" and do not get an ip address, router, or subnet mask. At the time of testing I have not yet set up the modem since I need the usb port for ssh until i get the hotspot working.

dnsmasq is already installed because I needed it to enable usb-gadget mode so I can ssh into the rpi. Following the instructions here (https://lozworld.com/lozwords/raspberry-pi-4b-as-an-ubuntu-2110-usb-gadget-tethered-to-an-ipad-pro) I made the following configuration changes:
/etc/dnsmasq.d/usb:

```
interface=usb0
dhcp-range=10.55.0.2,10.55.0.6,255.255.255.248,1h
dhcp-option=3
leasefile-ro
port=0
```

/etc/default/dnsmasq:

```
DNSMASQ_EXCEPT="lo"
```

Here are the commands I used to create the hotspot:

```
nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name Hostspot autoconnect yes ssid Hostspot
nmcli con modify Hostspot 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared
nmcli con modify Hostspot wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
nmcli con modify Hostspot wifi-sec.psk "veryveryhardpassword1234"
nmcli con up Hostspot
```

When the hotspot nmcli connection is up, running systemctl restart dnsmasq.service returns

```
Jul 22 16:01:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Jul 22 16:01:04 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1722]: dnsmasq: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Address already in use
Jul 22 16:01:04 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1722]: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Address already in use
Jul 22 16:01:04 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1722]: FAILED to start up
Jul 22 16:01:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jul 22 16:01:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 22 16:01:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

Here is the output of "nmcli con show":

```
connection.id:                          Hotspot
connection.uuid:                        afbf8081-cb19-4d5e-8517-38c222607984
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
connection.interface-name:              wlan0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1658497260
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.dns-over-tls:                -1 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
802-11-wireless.ssid:                   horsies
802-11-wireless.mode:                   ap
802-11-wireless.band:                   bg
802-11-wireless.channel:                0
802-11-wireless.bssid:                  --
802-11-wireless.rate:                   0
802-11-wireless.tx-power:               0
802-11-wireless.mac-address:            --
802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address:     --
802-11-wireless.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-11-wireless.mac-address-blacklist:  --
802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization:default
802-11-wireless.mtu:                    auto
802-11-wireless.seen-bssids:            E4:5F:01:97:CB:A2
802-11-wireless.hidden:                 no
802-11-wireless.powersave:              0 (default)
802-11-wireless.wake-on-wlan:           0x1 (default)
802-11-wireless.ap-isolation:           -1 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt:      wpa-psk
802-11-wireless-security.wep-tx-keyidx: 0
802-11-wireless-security.auth-alg:      --
802-11-wireless-security.proto:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pairwise:      --
802-11-wireless-security.group:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pmf:           0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-username: --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key0:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key1:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key2:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key3:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-flags: 0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-type:  unknown
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password: <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password-flags:0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wps-method:    0x0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.fils:          0 (default)
ipv4.method:                            shared
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           Hotspot
GENERAL.UUID:                           afbf8081-cb19-4d5e-8517-38c222607984
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        no
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/60
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/20
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.42.0.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.42.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7d33:50b:86ba:ca37/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
```

Comment: Welcome to AU. If you've solved it, why not post your solution as an answer to your question?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put (solved) in the question title and the answer inside the question. Click the **Answer Your Own Question** button below and write a full answer. Then accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔ and turn it green ✅. This will mark your question as solved and help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I uninstalled dnsmasq. dnsmasq-base seems to have taken over DHCP and made everything work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause was **UFW**. Which really isn’t suited for anything more than a simple single-connection home computer setup. It seems the connection sharing, together with some custom `dnsmasq` setup, was more than its interface lets you configure.

Disabling it for testing, made everything work.
Of course this is not a real solution.
A real solution for my case would be, to use `nftables` (or `iptables` for old systems) directly. Or a better GUI tool that uses them as its backend. And then set up the network correctly, by bridging the two networks (“connection sharing”), and setting the firewall to allow all bridge transit traffic (with neither side being the bridging machine itself) by default.
Even NetworkManager is more an enemy (/nanny) than a friend. Those simple tools always try to “simplify” things so much that they make anything but the dumbest common denominator way harder. So as a general answer, I recommend always trying with the full, manual tools (`ip`, `iw`, `nft`, …) first. And only if that works, and you understood what it does, and you need something to happen automatically, and can’t be bothered to script it yourself, maybe use any “smart” tools.

Another possible thing could be, to set multiple interfaces in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`. But that probably wasn’t it in my case. ;)